# Share printer through WiFi router

Tags: printer, network-printer

I have a Canon PIXMA MG3250 printer and TP-Link TL-MR3420 router running DD-WRT. I want to share my printer through my router.

How can I share my printer through the router in my local home network?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you followed the installation instructions to enable the Wi-Fi feature?

Comment: I installed it wit USB cable. The printer is connected to my PC which is connected to the router with enternet cable.

Comment: Do you have the installation disk? You will probably need to run setup again to enable the wireless option.

Comment: yes I have it but isn't there a way to do it through the router?

Comment: my pc doesn't have a wifi adapter and I will not be able to use the printer

Comment: This bears repeating...follow the instructions, follow the instructions, follow the instructions. Most wireless printers must be connected for the initial wireless setup. Once it's complete, the computer will send it's print jobs through the network to the printer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer is work perfect for me. Please set is as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run setup again (like you are installing it) and follow the instructions to enable the wireless feature.

Most wireless printers must be connected for the initial wireless setup. Once it's complete, the computer will send it's print jobs through the network to the printer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the on screen menu on your printer to connect to your wireless router and then install the driver on the computer. The driver software will ask you if you are connecting via usb or the network and will scan and locate the printer. I do this atleast a thousand times a day at work with a variety of printers.